# Get index value of Json by using curl and change the value(replace) with the other value. am not getting the index value, so that i can replace

Tags: javascript, json, module, drupal, webforms

am using webform in drupal and trying to convert json which is default generated by the rest api to custom json by using the curl operation in custom module, to change the some key value like title with label and so on...

am not getting how to do? can any body help here..

```html
<?php
 
namespace Drupal\custom_rest_services\Controller;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


class custom_rest_servicesController {
  public function converter_json_formio() { 
    
    

    return new jsonresponse( [

      'data' => $this->getResult(),
      'method' => 'GET',

    ]
    );
  }
  
  private function getResult(){
    

    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/install-dir/web/webform_rest/feedback_13/fields',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46QWRtaW5AMTIz'
      ),
    ));
    
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) { echo curl_error($ch); }
 
   
    else {
      
      $decoded = json_decode($result);
      print_r($decoded); // ARRAY
    }
curl_close($curl);

// return  $result;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: am using webform in drupal and trying to convert json which is default generated by the rest api to custom json by using the curl operation in custom module, to change the some key value like title with label and so on... if am able to change than same i can use to get the data from the mobile in custome way.